# How to add if condition in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array, and i want to add if condition in array.
Like :

```
$check = "failed";

$data = array(
    "personalizations" => array(
        array(
            "to" => array(
                array("email" => $userEmail, "name" => $userName)
            ),
            if(strpos($check, "SUCCESS") !== false){

            }else{
                "CC" => array(
                    array("email" => $adminEmail,"name" => $adminEmail)
                ) 
            } 
        )
    ),
    "from" => array("email" => $senderEmail, "name" => $senderName),
    "subject" => $subject,
    "content" => array(array("type" => "text/html", "value" => $body))
);
```

I want to send an email to the administrator. If the `$subject` does not have the word `success`, add CC array to the array, otherwise do not add cc.

I am getting error : `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put PHP control structures in the middle of defining an array like that. First create the array with the default values, then put the if-statement after and push new elements to the array, if needed.

Something like this:

```php
$data = array(
    "personalizations" => array(
        array(
            "to" => array(
                array("email" => $userEmail, "name" => $userName)
            ),
        )
    ),
    "from" => array("email" => $senderEmail, "name" => $senderName),
    "subject" => $subject,
    "content" => array(array("type" => "text/html", "value" => $body))
);

// Now add the condition
if(strpos($check, "SUCCESS") === false){
    $data['personalizations'][0]["CC"] = array(
        array("email" => $adminEmail,"name" => $adminEmail)
    ) 
}
```